# Sum of column between any two dates?

Tags: sql, select, sum, where-clause

Say I have a table with 3 columns, Name, Date, Test Score.

I want to find the sum of a person’s test scores between any two dates.

How would I do this in SQL?

Obviously I’d need the dates and the person (Name) as parameters, but I’m not sure where to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

You would typically use the parameters in the `where` clause of an aggregate query:

```
select sum(test_score) total_score
from mytable
where 
    date >= :start_date
    and date < :end_date
    and name = :name
```

`:start_date`, `:end_date` and `:name` are the parameters to the query, which are used to filter the dataset; the query always returns one row, with a single column called `total_score` that contains the sum of `test_score` for rows that satisfy the filtering predicataes. If no row matches, the returned value is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

With the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `marks` (
    `id`    INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name`  VARCHAR(255),
    `date`  DATETIME,
    `score` INT
);
```

The following select SQL will display a list of names and their sum:

```
SELECT
    `name`,
    SUM(`score`) AS `score_sum`
FROM `marks`
WHERE `date`
BETWEEN '2020-06-01 00:00:00'
    AND '2020-06-22 13:14:25'
GROUP BY `name`;
```

But for your solution, you might want to use:

```
SELECT
    SUM(`score`) AS `score_sum`
FROM `marks`
WHERE
    `name` = 'xxx'
AND `date`
    BETWEEN '2020-06-01 00:00:00'
    AND '2020-06-22 13:14:25';
```

Just keep in mind that if there is no value to SUM, a null will be returned.